# Seeking story about an animated zombie that appears to be intelligent

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember a fantasy short story, which I think I read in a magazine in the late 1980s or 1990s.  The main character was a female warrior, leader of a squad of troops.  They were on some kind of mission in a jungle, and I think I remember the main character complaining about the leather outfits they had to wear to protect themselves from natural hazards.  (I think there was a color illustration of her, dressed all in black leather.)

Somehow, she ends up on her own and is confronted with an animated zombie, which seems to be intelligent.  In this world, zombies are comparatively commonplace magic, but they have no cognitive abilities.  This zombie claims to be her enemy.  It almost convinces her, but eventually it turns out that it's actually just a mindless animation, being controlled by her second in command, who wants to replace her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by the answer I gave to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151392/story-about-two-wizards-from-earths-past-who-go-on-relativistic-trips-through-s/), I decided to look through my collection of *Dragon* issues, and I found the story I was asking about.  It's "Desperate Acts," by [Gordon Linzner](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?5376).

Here's the illustration that went with it:

[image: Desperate Acts]